# img src path gives first child only on hover jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have created a image div in html and below is the code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="TabMenu">
        <span><img src="images/ecom.png"></span>
        <span><img src="images/cms.png"></span>
        <span><img src="images/crm.png"></span>
        <span><img src="images/creative.png"></span>
        <span><img src="images/development.png"></span>
        <span><img src="images/qa.png"></span>
        <span><img src="images/mobile.png"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And now i written jquery

```
$(".container .TabMenu span").mouseover(function() {
    var imgpath = $('img').prop('src');
    alert(imgpath);
})
```

And when hover on any image, its displaying an alertbox with path of first image, but not the respective path. How can i retrieve respective image paths

And Now I am extending a question here itself

When i click on particular image its image should be changed and below is the code i wrote

I have two images as image1.png and image1-h.png, by this way i am using hovering style but

```
$(".container .TabMenu span").click(function(){
var newSrc = $('img', this).attr('src').replace(".", "-h.");
$('img', this).attr("src", newSrc);             
});
```

I have two images as image1.png and image1-h.png, by this way i am using hovering style by replacing the image name to "-h." but when i click this image ecom then its turns into ecom-h and cms to cms-h, how can i revert the original src path of that image so that, this image is active.
When i click on other image, previously clicked image should path come to original path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
var imgpath = $('img', this).prop('src');
```

In your case you are looking for a `img` tag in the whole document and taking first of them.

Comment: This is nice one! I'd explain what @Rafee actually did by using `$('img')` for best answer. +1 certainly at least because not everybody remember the second parameter to `jQuery()` which is `context`, although it may be really handy to use.

Comment: I am using this as short syntax, and how about only relative paths

Comment: How can i get the relative paths of images

Answer (score 2):

Use `this` to target the current element, and [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children) to select the image;

```
$(".container .TabMenu span").mouseover(function(){
    var imgpath = $(this).children('img').prop('src') ;
    alert(imgpath);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(".container .TabMenu span").mouseover(function(){
var imgpath = $(this).children("img").attr('src') ;
alert(imgpath);
```